# Use fs in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm just trying to read a file using `fs.readFileSync`, though it seems it cannot be found.

I made sure to declare it, added it within my constructor:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, {}> {
    private webAuth: auth0.WebAuth;
    fs: any;

    constructor(props: any, context: any) {
        super(props, context);
        this.fs = require('fs');
        this.webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
            clientID: conf.auth0.clientId,
            domain: conf.auth0.domain,
            responseType: 'token id_token',
            redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/login`
        });
    }
[...]
```

And used it in a simple function:

```
verifyToken = (token) => {

    console.log(this.fs);
    let contents = this.fs.readFileSync('../utils/public.key', 'utf8');
    console.log(contents);

}
```

But this raises an `Uncaught TypeError: _this.fs.readFileSync is not a function`. Is there a special way to include `fs` in Typescript ?

Comment: this your `Login` component is a browser component, right? Why are you trying to use the `fs` module?

Comment: If you are using wepback you could require file contents using `raw-loader`.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I can't imagine any case in which you would use `fs` inside a React component. Even though you can use React in the server to render stuff, the same code is supposed to run in the client, there's no way you can access  `fs` in the client.

If you want to use `fs` in the **server**, this is an example:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/index.html'), 'utf8', (error, data) => {
        // ...
    })
```

On your `package.json` file, make sure to have a dependency on node

```
"dependencies": {
 "@types/node": "^7.0.5"
}
```

And this is how my `tsconfig.json` file looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "./db/**/*",
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: ```fs```, in my case, is used to open a file that contains an Auth0 public key, which is used to verify a jwt token. I'm still fairly new to React, thanks for the advice !

Comment: The command of the `npm install @types/node` did it for me.

Answer (score 21):

Using `node -v 10.15.0` and [@types/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node):

It seems declaration has been rewritten...

`fs` definition is declared as a `module` so you should do:

`import fs from "fs"; // Without star`

compiled:

`var fs_1 = __importDefault(require("fs"));`

or

`const fs = require("fs");` instead of `require("fs").default;`

with star you will have `fs.default.TheFunctionYouWant` instead of `fs.TheFunctionYouWant`

The better way is to `console.log(fs);` to see what it is imported.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Latest implantation, you can import methods.

```
import { readFile, writeFile } from 'fs/promises';
```

And use directly...

```
// write
await writeFile('./file.json', content);

// read
const content = await readFile('./file.json');
```

Reference https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/

Comment: Is this possible to implement in React? (TSX)

Comment: I never try, but I believe it.

Comment: Don't forget to add `@types/node` to package.json: `"devDependencies": { "@types/node": "^20.3.3" }`

Comment: do i need to install fs/promises

Comment: No, `fs` is a native library.

Answer (score 4):

It may also help to install `@types/node`: `npm i --save-dev @types/node`