# In Angular application, I keep getting this error Cannot find module 'fs'

Tags: node.js, angular

In my service file, I import these four libraries:

```
import * as async from "async";
import * as officegen from "officegen";
import * as path from "path";
import * as fs from "fs";
```

While there's no problem with async,officegen and path. The fs line keeps giving this error:

> ERROR in src/app/matieres/matiere.service.ts(11,45): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'fs'.

In hopeless attempts, I tried these:

> npm install fs -g
>
> npm install fs --save
>
> npm install file-system -g
>
> npm install file-system --save

None of which worked 
This is really confusing.
Anyone can help?

Comment: `fs` is for backend node development. Why do you need it in Angular?

Comment: Have you wiped out your modules and reinstalled? `rm -r node_modules` then `npm i`

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm writing a service which contains the code of generating word documents. Then I will call that service in the app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `npm install --save-dev @types/node`

Might also need to check tsconfig.json for `"moduleResolution": "node"`

If that doesn't help, these other questions look similar:

[Cannot find module 'fs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546946/cannot-find-module-fs)

[Use fs in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048113/use-fs-in-typescript/43048371)