# Typescript: What's the best way to dynamically import a bunch of json files from a folder?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm changing the code of a working react app. There is a piece of code that imports and process a couple of json files:

```js
    import dataAjson from "./data/a.json";
    import dataBjson from "./data/b.json";

    datasets = [
              {
                info: {id: 'a'},
                data: processGeojson(dataAjson)
              },
              {
                info: {id: 'b'},
                data: processGeojson(dataBjson)
              }
            ]
```

I want to change this code so it will automatically process **all** files from the `./data` folder. I'm a newbie to TypeScript tool chain, and I don't know all the impacts that changing the `import` will have in my app.

The data files are somewhat large. All the files will be present in the data folder when the app starts. Since react executes in the client, maybe I must make a get request.

What's the best way to load these files? Or what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) module to read the directory `./data` and filter the files that end with `.json` and import it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'd like to know does it affect the app. Is it async? How will it affect the app load time? And the build time?

Comment: as long i knew it don't use async

Comment: here is an fs in typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048113/use-fs-in-typescript

Comment: Builtin modules are not supported in the browser. Reading files with `fs` will not cause them to be bundled like when using the import keyword