# import a SCSS file as a CSS string using Parcel, SASS and TypeScript

Tags: css, typescript, import, sass, parcel

Is there a way to import SCSS as CSS using Parcel Bundler + SASS + TypeScript?

I have a SCSS file called `file.scss`

```
div {
    span: {
        background: red
    }
}
```

so I want to import it as a CSS string in TypeScript, I'm tryng something like this:

```
import cssString from "./file.scss"

console.log(cssString)
         // ^^^^^^^^^ Expected value => div span: { background: red }
```

But isn't working properly.

So, i need to know, there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question, in "discussions" in the Parcel github and [Niklas Mischkulnig](https://github.com/mischnic) answered me, he told me that this can be done with Parcel 2, like this:

```
import cssString from "bundle-text:./file.scss;"
```

[follow the link to the question I made in the discussion forum of the parcel github](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/6333)

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke this method [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) directly

If you can't import `fs` in typescript, you can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43048113/use-fs-in-typescript/57233194)

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const cssStr = fs.readFileSync('./file.scss', { encoding: 'utf8' });
console.log(cssStr.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

Comment: I think I did not express myself well, I would like to have the CSS analyzed. In my initial question, I realized that I was wrong in the part where I talk about the result I expected, I already changed the question. basically, what I need is to import the SCSS in a string in CSS format. would you know to say if this is possible?